# looking to get diffs by groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

my dataset (ppf) is like the following:

| playerid | season | points | rebounds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2009-10 | 345 | 27 |
| 1234 | 2010-11 | 378 | 54 |
| 2345 | 2009-10 | 104 | 28 |
| 2345 | 2010-11 | 128 | 45 |

I want to get the difference in points and rebounds for each player by season and then return the playerid and season at the end, as well.

desired output:

| playerid | season | points | rebounds | points_diff | rebounds_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2009-10 | 345 | 27 | NaN | NaN |
| 1234 | 2010-11 | 378 | 54 | 33 | 27 |
| 2345 | 2009-10 | 104 | 28 | NaN | NaN |
| 2345 | 2010-11 | 128 | 45 | 24 | 17 |

I stored the playerid and season column names in identifiers and the stats names in cumstats_cols. I tried the following:

```
ppfs = ppf[identifiers + cumstats_cols].sort_values(['playerid','season']).groupby(['playerid'])[cumstats_cols].diff().reset_index()
```

but I can't tell if it's working correctly, because it does not return the playerid and season along with the differences.

appreciate the help!

**EDIT**
I would like to keep the original table and instead store the differences in additional columns.

Comment: `df.groupby(['playerid'], as_index=False).diff().join(df[['season']])`?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
new_df = df.assign(**df.groupby('playerid', sort=False)[['points', 'rebounds']].diff())
print(new_df)

   playerid   season  points  rebounds
0      1234  2009-10     NaN       NaN
1      1234  2010-11    33.0      27.0
2      2345  2009-10     NaN       NaN
3      2345  2010-11    24.0      17.0
```

Comment: hi. thanks for your response. I tried this and get the following error: "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
# sort the values
df.sort_values(['playerid','season'], inplace=True)

# group
df[['playerid','season']].join(df.groupby(['playerid'])
                                 [['points', 'rebounds']].diff()
                              )
```

Output:

```
   playerid   season  points  rebounds
0      1234  2009-10     NaN       NaN
1      1234  2010-11    33.0      27.0
2      2345  2009-10     NaN       NaN
3      2345  2010-11    24.0      17.0
```

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'... which is strange because the fields being differenced are all floats

Comment: Do you have other columns in your dataframe?

Comment: yes. 
Assists       float64
Blocks        float64
DefReb        float64
FieldGoals    float64
Fouls         float64
OReb          float64
Points        float64
Steals        float64
ThreeShots    float64
Turnovers     float64
ft_percent    float64
future        float64
name           object
playerid        int64
season         object

Comment: thanks for the response. unfortunately, that gave me many more rows than I originally had per playerid. There are now 5 lines per season for each player. there should only be 1 line per season for each player. I'm not sure why that's happening